# How to modify a single separator in between the text

Tags: perl, sed, awk

Hello:  I am looking to modify only one separator in between the following text either by awk, perl or sed

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,,,,k,l,m
```

to get the output as

```
a,b,c,d,e-f,g,,,,k,l,m
```

How to modify the nth separator ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/,/-/5' yourfile
```

Comment: +1 Nice! I always forget sed has that numeric argument, perfect for this situation.

Comment: @EdMorton Yea, though it is a `GNU` extension.

Comment: Thanks @sat! simple and crisp !!

Comment: Terrific, very compact. +1

Answer (score 1):

I can't beat sed, but this Perl command does what you ask

```
perl -aF, -pe"splice @F,4,2,qq{$F[4]-$F[5]};$_=join ',',@F" myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In general perl doesn't support counting the `s///` operations and making different choices on each one, but by using the `/e` flag you can do that yourself.

```
my $n = 0;
$string =~ s/,/++$n == 5 ? "-" : ","/eg;
```

will keep count of the number of times the substitution happens, and make a different change on the fifth time.

Comment: Thanks everyone...its really nice to have multiple solutions for a problem. surely learnt a few more tricks in perl and sed.

Answer (score 0):

or with perl

```
my @array = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
$array[4] = $array[4] . "-" . $array[5];
splice(@array, 5, 1);
```